# Why does the following code not generate a warning in MSVC

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I have a section of code that can be summarised as follows;

```
void MyFunc()
{
   int x;
'
'
   x;  
'
'
}
```

I would have thought that simply referencing a variable, without modifying it in anyway or using its value in anyway should generate a warning. In VS2003 it does neither, and it I need lint to pick it up.

I realise it doesn't effect execution, but since it is a piece of code that does nothing, and the programmer doubtless intended to do something, why is it not flagged?

Similarly would you expect *x = x* to be a warning?

**Edit:**  Modified question, as this constitutes a good candidate for a warning, but is not an error.  Replies suggest this is handled better with other compilers.  Will try out VS2008 later and post result.

Comment: why would it give a error, the syntax is correct.

Comment: Perhaps not an error, but certainly a warning.  if (x = y) is syntactically correct also, but generally not what the programmer intended.  I'd say any code that is in all probability not what the programmer intended should generate a warning, and I can't see that adding a statement to the code that does nothing the intention of most programmers at most times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a better compiler :-) Compiled with the -Wall and -pedantic flags, the GCC C++ compiler given this code:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    x;
}
```

produces this diagnostic:

```
ma.cpp:3: warning: statement has no effect
```

Comment: PC-Lint does the same for me, just very slowly ;)
error 522: (Warning -- Expected void type, assignment, increment or decrement)  Surprising how many of these I'm coming across linting a large code base, all errors in this case.

Comment: @Shane If PC-Lint is too slow, you might want to investigate GCC. The MinGW port (get the version at http://tdragon.net/recentgcc) will happily compile Windows code.

Answer (score 1):

Such code might occur in a template class for metaprogramming purposes.  For example, it might be some kind of a check whether `x` is accessible from the current context.  <strike>Yes, it doesn't affect the result of *execution*, but it does affect the result of *compilation*; this might be of aid to techniques like [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).</strike>

It seems, that it's of no help to compilation either.  Funciton bodies don't count for choosing the proper template for a function call.  And to check accessibility within a scope of a class, you have to use `using` operator for dependent names; this `using` operator itself being an accessibility check.

So, the code `x;` really has no effect.

Comment: @Pavel Shved, I don't see your point. If `x` is not accessible from the current context in a template instantiation, this results in a compilation error isn't it? Which beats SFINAE.

Answer (score 1):

You'd expect a warning unless you cast the expression to void, i.e.

```
void MyFunc()
{
   int x;

   (void)x;  

}
```

What warning level do you have set ?

Comment: /W4, highest level in VS2003, yup I'd expect a warning.  (As he spends a morning trwaling through lint output).

Comment: `gcc -Wall` gives: `lint.c:5: warning: statement with no effect`

Comment: Intel's ICC gives: `lint.c(5): remark #174: expression has no effect` and `lint.c(5): warning #592: variable "x" is used before its value is set`

Answer (score 0):

Both single-variable statements (such as **x;**) and self-assignment (such as **x=x**) are valid code in C++, so the compiler can't flag them as errors, but a good compiler is of course allowed to give a warning that they don't have any effect, and might be mistakes by the programmer. For example, the compiler g++ gives the warning "statement has no effect" for **x;**.